# timeline charts with rich ui

Tags: apache-flex, jsf, gwt, html, charts

I have a requirement to come up with a time line chart and a few more controls on a single page[with rich ui]. 
I have short listed
Flex, JSF[apache trinidad], html5, gwt these technologies.
None of them provide timeline charts on their own. I am looking at other options such as using third party libraries.
The chart should have drill down capabilities as well.
Let me know if there is any specific technology that I should try.

- regards

Comment: Would Google finance style charts work?  Doug McCune has a Flex example with source code available on [his blog](http://dougmccune.com/blog/2007/03/22/why-i-love-flex-charting-example/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Annotated Time Line](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/annotatedtimeline.html) is integrated with GWT.

Answer (score 0):

[Chronoscope](http://timepedia.org/chronoscope/demo/advanced/) is a GWT-based timeseries visualization tool.

Answer (score 0):

[amCharts](http://www.amcharts.com/) has a great timeline chart (Stock chart) based on Flex. You could try that.